# Get unique users per hour/day/month

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am quite new to the LINQ expressions and need to create a chart in MVC.

The pie chart has the labels part:
If the case is hour it will have 1,2...24
If day then 1,2...31
If month then 1,2...12

So for each case I need to get the unique users by UserID as my table contains conversation data where a user exists multiple times. Then I must return the corresponding array.
For now I have:

```
ViewBag.monthArray= db.Conversation.ToList().GroupBy(p => DateTime.Parse(p.Date_Time).Month).ToArray();
```

And the chart code:

```
var monthChart= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.monthArray));
var areaChartData = {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Month Count',
            fillColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            data: [monthChart]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I count the unique users for each case?
How can I separate the count per hour/day/month?

Comment: question, what regarding day, it happened in `1-1-2019` and the other one happened in `2-1-2019` their day would be the same, would they be count in the same `day`? also in `hour`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by multiple fields by passing in an anonymous object like this

```
ViewBag.monthArray= db.Conversation.ToList().GroupBy(p => new { DateTime.Parse(p.Date_Time).Month, p.UserID })
                .ToArray();
```

if you inspect that result, you can see what else you can do. If you just need to JSON the month and the UserIDs, add a .Select(g => new { g.Key.Month, g.Key.UserID }) before ToArray.